# How can I use microdata to optimize my Website on search engine platforms?

Tags: html

I have tried using microdata in my html to optimize my website for search engines but it didn't work out. Please I need guide lines on how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean microdata? This should help you out:

https://schema.org/docs/gs.html

Something like this

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
```

Or did you mean meta tags, like description, keywords, etc?

Comment: Please Microdata I meant

Comment: I have found a lot of information about microdata from the link. I believe it will be of great help. Thanks